# Speakers' location in determining venir vs. ir

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, gramática

In English, we use the word "come" very loosely (at least in day-to-day spoken English):

- Want to come over to my place later?
- Can I come over to your house for New Years'?
- Can you come meet me at the coffee shop after work?
- I'll bring pictures of the kids the next time I come visit you in Florida.
- etc.

In other words, "come" can be used regardless of where the speaker and the listener are located, either now or in the future.

In Spanish, I've heard that *venir* is supposed to be used only for situations where the listener is coming to the speaker's current location, and *ir* should be used for other situations (the same goes for *traer* and *llevar*). Is this the rule? If so, is it just in formal, written contexts, or does it apply to spoken language too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you use "venir" when moving to the speaker's current location, and "ir" to another location. However, as in English, you can say "¿Quieres venir a mi casa?" without being in said place.

The RAE has a very simple but good explanation:

- **Venir** Llegar a donde está quien habla.
- **Ir** Moverse de un lugar hacia otro apartado de quien usa el verbo ir y de quien ejecuta el movimiento.

From rae.es [Venir](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=venir) and [Ir](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ir).

Comment: It's that simple. However, I've noticed that in Catalan-speaking areas, at least in Mallorca, they often say "ya vengo" instead of "ya voy".

Comment: Mallorca it's a catalan (or whatever term you want to use) speaking area and that mistake it's a literal translation of "Ja venc" cataln for "ya voy"