# Voy vs. Vengo, both correct?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos

So I have a doubt. I was talking with a cousin and I said:

> Entonces de pronto **vengo** en enero.

And he said, isn't it `voy` ? I thought about it and I think that both are correct.

Am I wrong?

Comment: See http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/speakers-location-in-determining-venir-vs-ir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

`Vengo` is **coming from**.

`Ir` is **going somewhere** or going to do something (including leaving the current place).

I would have used `voy` too in that context. I live in USA now and my family in Spain. A phone conversation would be like:

> My father: Hijo, vas a **venir** (aquí) a España por Navidades este año?
>
> Me: No. No **voy** este año. Esta vez no puedo cogerme vacaciones, papá (No voy a **ir**).

If I could make it there for Christmas, once there, I could then be saying:

> **Vengo** desde USA con regalos para todos!

And If I'm talking about leaving a place:

> Me **voy** el viernes de vuelta a casa.
>
> Si no me suben el sueldo me **voy** de la empresa.

Since I would be already there (in their location). I used `vengo` for the meaning of coming (or coming back) from somewhere:

> **Vengo** del trabajo, por eso todavía llevo puesto traje y corbata.
>
> **Vengo** de ver a los abuelos. Os mandan recuerdos.

Note that you could be saying "Entonces de pronto **vengo** en enero." Think about this context: You are explaining the situation that got you there, and for some reason you are using "presente histórico":

> Me entero de que mi madre está muy enferma. Entonces, de pronto, cojo un avión y (me) **vengo** aquí en enero para cuidarla. Pasan tres semanas y ella empieza a mejorar...

But I guess that that is not what you where trying to say, since is a very tricky use of the verb tenses, so:

`Vengo` from `Venir` (people come to where you are) for **coming from**: I come from (there)

`Voy` from `Ir` (to move to a different place from the starting point) for **going**:  I'm going (there)

**Edit**: (*kudos* para dockeryz por señalar este uso) parece ser que en algunos países latinoamericanos es aceptable el uso informal de "vengo" por "voy" cuando la acción implica inmediatez (como una forma de extender el "ya vengo"/"ya mismo estoy de vuelta" similar a decir "enseguida estoy allí" en lugar de "enseguida estaré allí"). En cierto países latinoamericanos la expresión "me vengo" tiene además connotaciones sexuales:

> "Me vengo" es *slang* para *eyacular*

Comment: +1 For usage of examples (and for generate an answer much better than mine).

Comment: I disagree that Vengo only means `coming from`.. `Viene` means `he's coming`... Ya vengo... `I'm on my way`

Comment: Actually that would be a regional difference. In Spain nobody would use "ya vengo" but "ya voy". e.g. if someone is rushing you to do something yo say "que ya voy..." or if they ask if you already left to go somewhere "estoy yendo (estoy de camino)". Thanks for pointing out that regional difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as dockeryz said, it's not always coming from. That's the main reason I asked the question. It may be relevant to say that I am latinamerican and our spanish use is slightly different as in Spain, not necessarily incorrect. Since it is a place (2 hours from where I am) that I go often to I used `vengo`. I think it is an exception in use. The thing is I am not using it as 'leaving' a place but rather as coming from x to y. hmmmm

Comment: @Joze Well, you are asking if both are correct, but `vengo` in your context (and in the dockeryz example) would be a slang. I'm also a latinamerican and we would never use `Ya vengo` with the `Ya voy` meaning

Comment: So to be brief, it's not correct yes?

Comment: @Joze, then the disagreement you had with your cousin over the word might be due to a regional difference, not about the meaning/usage of the words. He corrected you as I would have had (and there was no much context to infer that  particularity or region, time to destination, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest difference for these two terms is to consider them as this:

- Voy: is like going, from a current place to another place.
- Vengo: is like coming, from another place to a current place.

So, "I'm going **to** your house" and "I'm coming **from** Canada", would be, "**Voy** a tu casa" and "**Vengo** de Canada".

Comment: +1 simple and answers the question

Answer (score 1):

These are different verbs:

- *vengo* is for *venir*
- *voy* is for *ir*

*vengo en enero* sounds better to me like "I'm coming in january" while "I'm going in january" looks to be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

### La preposición utilizada

It all depends upon the preposition used after the verb.  Although they have different contexts as far as their definition, they still mean relatively the same thing.

Although, using the wrong verb will sound a bit strange.

- Vengo de <== Coming from
- Vengo a <== Come to
- Vengo por <== Coming by ( as in `Come by airplane` )
- Vengo con <== Come with
- Ir de <== Go from
- Ir a <== Go to
- Ir por <== Go to/by ( as in .. pass by, or go by... e.g to go by plane, to go by the school )
- Ir con <== Go with

### Using your example

- I'm coming in January
- I'm going in January

**The verb `ir` does have a distinct feature though.. it is reflexive.**

`Voy en enero` is very dry spoken and sounds a bit primitive. Instead, you would say

> Entonces de pronto me voy en enero

Comment: "voy en enero" doesn't sound dry to me. "voy" doesn't necessarily imply "**me** voy". You are changing the meaning from "I go to a place" to "I leave a place": "Te viene mejor el mes que viene? Entonces voy en enero a visitarte, y no en diciembre"

Answer (score 1):

There's (at least) one situation in which using "Entonces de pronto vengo en Enero" is correct:

- if you're physically with your cousin at the time.
- if you will be elsewhere before January
- if you will get back to the place you are with your cousin.

In that case, "voy" is incorrect, because you'd be coming back. The equivalent in English would be "So, I might come visit you (again) in January."

A common usage of the phrase: when you're going out, you might say to your wife "Vengo a las 8", and it would have the same meaning as "Vuelvo a las 8".

I think in general, if you can substitute "Vuelvo" in place of "Vengo", the sentence would be correct.

Comment: +1 por ofrecer otras alternativas al uso de "vengo"

Answer (score 0):

There, you're omitting the subject in your sentence (in this case, I "me" (first person)).

> Entonces de pronto **yo** *vengo* en enero.

If you review the "[conjugación del verbo (ir)](http://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/conjugacion/112-ir.html)" the most adequate conjugation of subject "I (yo)" for your sentence is:

> Entonces de pronto ***voy*** en enero.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use "Vengo en Enero" if you are referring to going to USA from Spain for example, while you are in Spain.

You have to use "**Voy**", because "**Vengo de**" means **coming from** somewhere (while already here) and "**Voy a**" means **going to** somewhere (while being here).

Answer (score 0):

Voy means that I am going somewhere.
Vengo means that I am coming here.
I am going to New York in june (you are in Japan)
Voy a Nueva York en junio (you are in Japan)

I am coming to New York in june (you are in New York but planning to come back)
Vengo a Nueva York en junio (you are in New York but planning to come back)

Cheers!